# Is there a command in powershell to get the IP information of a MAC

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to have a simple command to resolve a MAC address to an IP. Is this even possible? I know the MAC address I am looking to get the IP address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will give if the IP address **if** you already have the MAC/IP association in your ARP table:

```
arp -a | select-string "00-1c-87-c0-1c-5d" |% { $_.ToString().Trim().Split(" ")[0] }
```

returns

```
192.168.10.95
```

If you do not have the record in your ARP table, then I don't think that there is an easy way to do it.

One way would be to install [arping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping) and call it in a similar fashion from your Powershell script.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Get-NetNeighbor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netneighbor?view=win10-ps) allows you to get the IP addresses from the MAC addresses if present in the ARP cache. For example:

```bsh
Get-NetNeighbor -LinkLayerAddress ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
```

will list all IP addresses with the MAC address equal to `FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF`.

Comment: Good answer.  One nice feature of this method is that you can use wildcards in the MAC address.  To get just the IP as in the accepted answer, you can pipe the output through to `| Select IPAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.ehow.com/how_5255463_use-mac-address-ip-address.html) describes how to use `arp` on the command line to do this. You might also be able to use the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` [WMI object](http://lantoolbox.com/news/windows-powershell-for-network-administration/) to do this straight from PowerShell.

Comment: I am looking for a signal command that will give me the Ip address of a known MAC address of some system. I dont want the mac address of my own interface.

Comment: ARP will only resolve addresses in your subnet (your "peers" directly under the nearest switch). If you're looking for broader resolution you might want to consult a hacker...

Comment: I am wanting to use the protocol rarp. Its a reverse lookup of a MAC addess. I hear alot of great things that powershell can do. I was hoping it could do this one. I would love to have a script that would run and tell me everything thats on the network. I know there is software like solarwinds that will do it It would be nice to have a small script to do the same thing.

Comment: Solarwinds is a application that works by a process of discovery and querying the the arp tables on all the routers it can find on the network.  If that could be replaced with a few lines of powershell script, they'd have been out of business some time ago.